# RecyclerView Divider Space

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I create a list with a simple RecyclerView and CardView without any style properties.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/shops_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And I get the expected result when I run in android 4.2.2 device like the following screenshot.

[image: Screenshot in android 4.2.2 Genymotion emulator]

But, when I run in Android version 6.0.1, there is no space between CardView item like the following.

[image: Screenshot in android 6.0.1 real device]

I would like to get some space between CardView item like the above screenshot. Is need to add space or divider height manually? Please help :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"`in `CardView`.

> CardView adds padding in platforms pre-L to draw shadows. In L, unless you set `useCompatPadding=true`, there should not be any gap.